# phpWord подчеркивание длиной в ширину строки

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

Здравствуйте, использую библиотеку [phpWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) возникла необходимость задать подчеркнутую строку на всю ширину документа, т.е. как подчеркнутый текст только оставить еще пустое место, пример в изображении. Подчеркнуть сам текст легко, а вот сделать что бы строка дальше была подчеркнутой не удалось, можно догнать табами (\t) но для этого нужно угадать сколько табов поместить нужно в строку, и сколько места в строке уже занято. Может кто подскажет как это в word делается, и тогда получится найти аналог в phpWord.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

судя по примеру, Вам нужно сделать горизонтальную линию в самом шаблоне docx, нужной длины (для обозначения места записи, а-ля "поле для записи"), а в самой строке вставить переменную. Таким образом у вас длина подчёркивания будет всегда на полную ширину документа, независимо от длины текста в переменной.

Второй вариант - посчитать кол-во символов в строке, и в переменную добивать пустые символы, считая: число символов + пробел * (длина строки - число символов).

надеюсь ответ для Вас полезен и актуален.